# Handling [CustomStringConvertible] versus CustomStringConvertible in Swift func param

Tags: swift, swift5, implicit-conversion

I've implemented a simple generic type wrapper (used in setting up Picker configurations). The idea is to wrap any type that supports a `.description` in a type erased container:

```
struct PickerDataValue: Equatable {
   let value: CustomStringConvertible
   var description: String? { get { value.description }}
   init(_ t: CustomStringConvertible) { value = t }
   
   // So that we can drop() a PickerDataValue from an array of the same
   static func == (lhs: PickerDataValue, rhs: PickerDataValue) -> Bool {
      lhs.value.description == rhs.value.description
   }
}
```

All fine, but when I'm working with getting data into and out of this structure, I ran into something a bit unexpected. My original attempt:

```
struct PickerDataSet: Equatable {
   // An array of values that populate into the picker columns
   let values: [PickerDataValue]
   
   // Convenience
   init(from v: [CustomStringConvertible]) { self.init(v.map { PickerDataValue($0) }) } // <--
   init(from v: CustomStringConvertible) { self.init(PickerDataValue(v)) }
   init(_ v: [PickerDataValue]) { values = v }
   ...
```

This results in `PickerDataSet(from: someArrayOfStrings)` evaluating to `[{["string1", "string2"...]}]` which is what you get if you apply `.description` to an `Array`.

The intended evaluation would be `[{value "string1"}, {value "string2"}...]`.

It turns out `init(from v: [CustomStringConvertible])` never gets called, because its sister `init(from v: CustomStringConvertible)` is greedy. Since `Array` is itself `CustomStringConvertible` I end up with a `String` representation of the array being fed into the latter `init` function. In other words, the compiler prioritizes implicit conversion using `.description` over the natural type of an argument.

This is pretty easy to fix, but the solution just feels "wrong" to me. Then again, maybe I'm used to Scala versus Swift (still learning the latter) and a more strongly typed functional language that just deals with this stuff more elegantly.

Anyhow replacing my two `init` functions with this one solves the problem:

```
struct PickerDataSet: Equatable {
   // An array of values that populate into the picker columns
   let values: [PickerDataValue]
   
   // Convenience
   init(from v: CustomStringConvertible) {
      if let asArray = v as? [CustomStringConvertible] {
         self.init(asArray.map { PickerDataValue($0) })
      } else {
         self.init(PickerDataValue(v))
      }
   }
   init(_ v: [PickerDataSet]) { values = v }
   ...
```

Like I said, it feels wrong, but it works. Any comments? Is this a bad approach in Swift and is there a better way to handle this kind of problem? Specifically what bothers me is that the compiler can't distinguish between passing in a `CustomStringConvertible` and `[CustomStringConvertible]` but, I understand why, more or less. Seems wrong that the compiler would not look at the type first, and then apply implicit conversion (to `.description`) but apparently it does it the other way around.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if your code made more sense, you are mixing PickerDataSet, PickerDataValue and PickerDataCell wildly. Also, when I try to fix your code so it compiles then the correct init is called so this is not reproducible.

Comment: Sorry, something got smashed in the first post. Fixed it. There are only two types, `PickerDataValue` (the value wrapper) and `PickerDataSet` (a collection of the wrapper).

Comment: That looks like the code I have but as I said, the problem isn't reproducible for me. An easy way to handle situations like this is of course not to have the same parameter label in both init functions